# Obtaining a timestamp every minute from a database

Tags: mysql

This is my table structure:

```
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| uid        | char(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cid        | char(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ip_address | char(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user_agent | char(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| open_date  | datetime  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| referrer   | char(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| environ    | text      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| country    | char(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to get a timestamp every minute within a range.

```
select DATE_ADD(open_date,interval 1 minute)
as m from open_track.camp_open  where  open_date between
"2009-05-13 00:00:00"   and "2009-05-13 23:59:59"  limit 10;
```

outputs

```
+---------------------+
| m                   |
+---------------------+
| 2009-05-13 00:01:01 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:02 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:03 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:03 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:04 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:05 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:06 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:08 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:08 |
| 2009-05-13 00:01:09 |
+---------------------+
```

Please advise me.

Comment: Exactly why would you want to do that? There are tons of easier ways to get current time.

Comment: i want a count of opens hit per minute

Answer (score 1):

> i want a count of opens hit per minute

```
  SELECT COUNT(*),
         DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
    FROM camp_open
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

Comment: This is returning +----------+------------------------------------------+ | COUNT(*) | DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i', open_date) | +----------+------------------------------------------+ | 476414 | NULL | +----------+------------------------------------------+

Comment: @soumen: only one line? do you have any rows where `open_date` not equal to NULL?

Comment: mysql> select count(*),year(open_date) from open_track.camp_open group by year(open_date);
+----------+-----------------+
| count(*) | year(open_date) |
+----------+-----------------+
| 41206553 |            2009 |
| 44474388 |            2010 |
|  4896681 |            2011 |
+----------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (1 min 30.70 sec)

mysql>

Answer (score 0):

@zerkms

thanks a lot !!!!

Query to find the highest count in a minute on a particular day

SELECT COUNT(*) as c ,DATE_FORMAT(open_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as m 
FROM camp_open 
where  open_date between "2009-05-13 00:00:00"   and "2009-05-13 23:59:59"
GROUP BY m order by c desc limit 1;